# joomla ADD html in contacts edit on address

Tags: joomla-3.x, contact

Im trying to put html `<br>` inside the form Addrees of Contacts: Edit in Joomla.

But after saving, it erases the html code.

Any help? Thanks.

[image: Link image:]

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a line break by pressing "Enter"?

Comment: yes and It not work. Dont do the paragraph in front page. besides i want to put some html code to read other icons. TY

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file administrator/components/com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml and find field below code

```
<field
  name="address"
  type="textarea"
  label="COM_CONTACT_FIELD_INFORMATION_ADDRESS_LABEL"
  description="COM_CONTACT_FIELD_INFORMATION_ADDRESS_DESC"
  rows="3"
  cols="30"
```

Add filter to it like below:

```
<field
  name="address"
  type="textarea"
  label="COM_CONTACT_FIELD_INFORMATION_ADDRESS_LABEL"
  description="COM_CONTACT_FIELD_INFORMATION_ADDRESS_DESC"
  rows="3"
  cols="30"
  filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"
```

Note: it is bad idea to modify core files. Instead override using output overrides.
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854626/override-components-com-users-models-forms-login-xml-joomla-2-5